# Django / Python - Extract Date from DateTimeField

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

Take the example model as follows:

```
import datetime

class Calendar(models.Model)

    def now():
        return datetime.date.today()

    def 24hrslater():
        return datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)

    now = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
    24hrslater = models.DateTimeField(default=24hrslater)
```

Is there a way to extract just the date from these date time fields? I have tried the following (as suggested on another thread):

```
todaysdate = now.date()
```

But had no success with it. The error that comes up on the command line when running "python manage.py check" is:

```
AttributeError: 'DateTimeField' object has no attribute 'date'
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: This code is not valid python. You can't have identifiers that start with digits. `24hrslater` can't be a function name or class attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understand your question correctly, but you can get the date from DateTimeFields like this.

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Calendar(models.Model):

    now = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    twenty_four_hours_later = models.DateTimeField(
        default=lambda: timezone.now() + timezone.timedelta(hours=24))

c = Calendar()
print(c.now.date())
print(c.twenty_four_hours_later.date())
```

Comment: You should prefer using `django.utils.timezone` over the stdlib `datetime`, since django expects timezone aware datetimes. Also the default argument to a `DateTimeField` should return a datetime, not just a date. And avoid defining utility functions inside the class declaration. Only declare methods or `@staticmethod`s

Answer (score 4):

```
def now():
    return datetime.today().date()
```

this will return the current date

```
Calendar.objects.filter(datetimefield__date='your_date')
```

Comment: Is there a way to extract the date directly from the DateTimeField object though? So that way, it would work for any date-time that is inputted into the model?